# Flutter custom painter feedback: Blending new layer with old ones

Tags: flutter, image, dart, paint, feedback

I want to build a feedback system where I have an input image, apply some transformations to it, and then use the transformed image as an input for the next frame (with some kind of blending inbetween).

My idea was to use a CustomPaint. I would have a CustomPaint which simply draws a circle in the middle of the canvas. A second CustomPaint would then take an image input, apply some transformations & blending. The output of that custompaint should then be fed into itself again the next time paint is called.

Is this something that can be done with CustomPaints, or is there a better way to do this? I don't understand how I can get save the output of one frame and input it in the second one.

Any help or suggestions are highly appreciated!